# Fetch minimum value for each NTILE bucket in Hive

Tags: postgresql, hive, window-functions

I am trying to partition the data into percentiles (100 equal buckets) using NTILE window function for each merchant_id ordered by score column. The output of the query will contain merchant_id, score, and percentile for every record in the source table. (Sample code below)

```
CREATE TABLE merchant_score_ntiles
AS
SELECT merchant_id, score, NTILE(100) OVER (PARTITION BY merchant_id ORDER BY score DESC) as percentile
FROM merch_table
```

This will return sample output as follows:

> merchant_id,score,percentile 
> 1001,900,1 
> 1001,800,1 
> 1001,760,1 
> 1002,900,2 
> 1002,800,2 
> 1002,750,2

Is there a way we can return only the minimum score for each merchant_id based on percentile column such as below?

> merchant_id,score,percentile 
> 1001,760,1 
> 1002,750,2

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function in subquery before using `NTILE` window function

```
SELECT merchant_id, 
       score, 
       NTILE(100) OVER (PARTITION BY merchant_id ORDER BY score DESC) as percentile
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY merchant_id ORDER BY score) rn
    FROM merch_table
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```